# Using IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM vw_pse_top_active) in function is returning ERROR: syntax error at or near "SELECT"

Tags: postgresql

```
--    create or replace function iq_get_pse_top_active()
--    RETURNS TABLE`enter code here`
--    (
    symbol character varying, 
    orderbook integer, 
    company_name character varying,
    logo_url character varying,
    display_logo boolean,
    base_url character varying, 
    stock_value real,
    volume integer,
    last_trade_price numeric(20,4), 
    last_trade_date timestamp without time zone, 
    prev_close_price numeric(20,4), 
    gain_loss numeric(20,4),
    percentage numeric(20,2)
    ) 
    VOLATILE
    AS $body$
    BEGIN
    RETURN query
    
    select  symbol,
    orderbook,
    company_name,
    logo_url,
    display_logo,
    base_url, 
    stock_value,
    volume, 
    last_trade_price::numeric(20,4),
    last_trade_date, 
    prev_close_price::numeric(20,4), 
    gain_loss::numeric(20,4),
    percentage::numeric(20,2)
     
    FROM
    (

    /* This is where the error. What is a good replacement for this condition? */

    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM vw_pse_top_active) 
        THEN
        (select v.symbol,
         v.orderbook,
         v.company_name,
         v.logo_url,
         v.display_logo,
         v.base_url, 
         v.stock_value,
         v.volume, 
         v.last_trade_price::numeric(20,4),
         v.last_trade_date, 
         v.prev_close_price::numeric(20,4), 
         v.gain_loss::numeric(20,4),
         v.percentage::numeric(20,2)
         from vw_pse_top_active ) as v 
    ELSE

        /* If the table above is empty then this table will be used */
    
        (select h.symbol,
         h.orderbook,
         h.company_name,
         h.logo_url,
         h.display_logo,
         h.base_url, 
         h.stock_value,
         h.volume, 
         h.last_trade_price::numeric(20,4),
         h.last_trade_date, 
         h.prev_close_price::numeric(20,4), 
         h.gain_loss::numeric(20,4),
         h.percentage::numeric(20,2)
         prod_stock_daily_top_history ) as  h   
        END IF;
    ) as t;
    END;
    $body$ 

/* end of code */
```

Comment: You can't mix SQL statements and `plpgsql` conditionals e.g. `IF EXISTS`. Your best bet is to use [Dynamic SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) and run the `SELECT 1 FROM vw_pse_top_active` test to set the table name and then substitute that name into the dynamic query.

Comment: Your statement *IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM vw_pse_top_active)*. Does **not** indicate what your comments suggest. It  determines if the name exists, it does determine not if it contains data.

Comment: @Belayer,  I want to check if vw_pse_top_active ( it's a view object ) has at least 1 row. If there is no data then I want to run the other select to retrieve the historical data.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver,  I am trying to find out if table ( using a view object ) has at least one record to decide which data to retrieve.  The java script will just call this function.

Comment: Bottom line is you cannot have a conditional statement inside a SQL query.